# How to call a excel macro from .net Web service?

Tags: c#, excel, web-services

I am trying to call a excel macro from the my web service but it is unable to initialize the Excel.Application object. This is giving error at following line:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Even for publish the web service i am using the service account in the Application pool in the IIS.

Can anyone tell me how can we call a macro in c#.net web service.

Thanxs in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting might be from:

1. Excel not installed on server
2. The user executing your IIS application pool doesn't have enough privileges to run excel.

After coping with that, you can check how to run a macro [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683)

Comment: Excel is already installed on the Server. and Account also have the full previlages.

Comment: Excel is already installed on the Server. and Account also have the full previlages.